# How do I solve $y'''-5y''+11y'-15y=0$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

How do I solve the following linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients? 
$$y'''-5y''+11y'-15y=0.$$

Please help.

Thank you.

Comment: Find the roots of the characteristic equation: $k^3-5k^2+11k-15 = 0$.

Comment: You know, **Jo Mo**, putting "solve linear ordinary differential equation with constant coefficients" into a search engine works wonders!

Answer (score 1):

Consider the characteristic equation corresponding to the differential equation. $$m^3-5m^2 + 11m - 15 = 0$$ Use rational root theorem, to conclude that $m=3$ is a root. Now factorizing the characteristic equation gives us $(m-3)(m^2-2m+5)$. The roots of the characteristic equation are $m=3, 1 \pm 2i$. Hence, the solution of $$y'''-5y''+11y'-15 = 0$$ is given by
$$y(x) = a e^{3x} + be^x \sin(2x) + c e^x \cos(2x)$$

Comment: I wish there were an option for a *sideways* vote to indicate "this is spoonfeeding". Oh well. Guess I'll just comment!